# How to fix it ? org.json.JSONException: Response cannot be parsed as JSON data

Tags: android, json

> 03-27 11:59:09.438 4577-4577/com.example.mealitup W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received
>       org.json.JSONException: Response cannot be parsed as JSON data
>           at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:158)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried and the json (if possible).

Answer (score 2):

**Use Retrofit**

**1. Create an interface**

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET(Constants.JSON)
    Call<List<MyModel>> getJSON();
}
```

**2. Call this function and pass URL to fetch JSON**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl( "www.myJSONexample.com")
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<List<MyModel>> call = request.getJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<MyModel>> call, @NonNull 
   Response<List<MyModel>> response) {
            List<MyModel> jsonResponse = response.body();
            String str = jsonResponse.get( 0 );
            String str2 = jsonResponse.get( 1 );
   }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Recipe>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FAIL: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```